# Use of undeclared Identifier 'image'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
     {

         [self emailImage:image];
     }
     ];

    [picker release];
}
```

I am new to iOS and have just started developing apps. I know Swift language but I have to complete this in Objective C. I am not able to resolve this error.

The link to the images are as follows:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: are you want to get image in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)photoPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType;
    mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];


    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage ])
    {

        UIImage * image = (UIImage*) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        imageAddView.image  = [UIImage squareImageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(640, 640)];

        [photoPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

}
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like,

```
  -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

 UIImage *image=info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
 [self emailImage:image];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
 { 
     //perform anything after dismissing image picker controller
 }
 ];
 }
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this but this ends up giving error [UIImage retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fdb7602e000